# VBA Switching Worksheets Disabled

Tags: vba, excel

I've created workbook with Battleships game. The whole "program" works great. Its shared workbook with 2 worksheets and battleground on each one. Its creating random ships, mark hits/misses and calculate hits/misses %. Almost finished it but I would like to improve it even more. My goal is to create code which will not allow another player to look into my battleground and see ships. Tried to use `Deactivate` module and `Application.ScreenUpdate = False` but still when I click another worksheet or hold it I can see ships.

Any alternatives or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xlSheetVeryHidden` property, which can't be unhidden using the regular right-click on the Sheet Tab (but only by VBA code).

The sample code below checks which Username is opening the workbook, and accordingly hides or shows the relevant sheets.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Select Case Environ("Username")
    Case "Me" ' modify to your PC username
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Case "Player"  ' modify to your opponent PC username
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Had to modify it a bit to my needs but `xlSheetVeryHidden` works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to hide the worksheet in question?
`Application.ScreenUpdate = False` will only prevent the worksheet from updating cells.